# Browsing the html page from virtual directory works in IE and no working in Chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

`localhost/rupeshwebsite/RJ.htm`
this url works fine IE and 
I am developing a windows application using C#. We are developing application as a generalised one.We are giving scripts  in a notepad file so that they can place in the script in their web site or html page it should work.
As a part of testing i created a separate project and put the script in html page  and created the virtual directory for that project named rupeshwebsite. 
When i browse the html page from the virtual directory, in IE the  url works fine and displaying the  details in browser. but when i paste the same url in chrome or firefox it won't work. Inside the script we are calling Json Rest service method using $.getJSON Function.Why the url is not working in chrome or firefox. Instead if replaced with my PC ip address in the url it's working fine in chrome and firefox. What is the error. Here i am attaching my script code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = invokeService();
        function invokeService() {
            $(document).ready(function () {


                //   Additional way of calling WCF service using getJSON() JQuery method
                $.getJSON('http://192.168.2.84/WcfJsonRestService/Albums/rjinfo', {},
                    function (data) {
                        alert('hello ' + data);
                        var value = '';
                        value +="<table width='100%'>";
                        value +="<tr><th colspan='2' style='width:100%; background-color:Gray;color:Black; font-weight:bold;'>R.J Details</th></tr>";
                        var newrow = data.split('$');
                        for (var vloop = 0; vloop < newrow.length; vloop++) {
                            var newvalue = newrow[vloop].split(',');
                            value +="<tr ><td align='center'><img src='images/" + newvalue[2] + "' height='100' width='100' /></td><td align='center' style='background-color:lightgray; color:black;'> " + newvalue[1] + '<br/>' + newvalue[3] + newvalue[4] + '</td></tr>';

                        }
                        value +='</table>';
                       document.getElementById('divrjdetails').innerHTML = value;
                    });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome on right mouse click there is 'Inspect Elements' option which will open debug console, you can get some information about the error from there. And for Firefox you can use the Firebug add-on for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the path ?

In Firefox this should work (should work in chrome, too):

```
file:///C:/your/path/to/rupeshwebsite/RJ.htm
```